# XSL Test error at least one contains instead of only the one

Tags: testing, xslt, xpath, xsl-fo

With several xml documents containing topic elements and only one file containing a topic element with attribute product="OPTION".

I'd like to write OPTION if the attribute is set for the topic and TOTO if no attribute exists for the topic.

The problem is that actally if at least one file contains the attribute product="OPTION" OPTION is written on every generated pdf page.

```
<xsl:template name="insertBodyEvenHeader">
  <xsl:param as="xs:string" name="flow-name" select="'even-body-header'" />
  <fo:static-content flow-name="{$flow-name}">
    <fo:block xsl:use-attribute-sets="__body__even__header">
      <xsl:choose>
         <xsl:when test="topic/@product='OPTION'">
            <fo:inline xsl:use-attribute-sets="title__option">
               <xsl:text>OPTION</xsl:text>
            </fo:inline>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>TOTO</xsl:otherwise>
       </xsl:choose>   
    </fo:block>  
  </fo:static-content>
</xsl:template>
```

Would you be so kind to help me dealing with that test? thansks, best regards

Comment: Sorry, but you don't provide enough context to be able to help you. What is the context of the `xsl:choose`? Also, your XSLT tests for 'OPTION2', not 'OPTION'.

Comment: Hello I'm trying to set a header in dita opentoolkit statics contents
normal header is processed in the otherwise with TOTO
specific headers containing attribute product='OPTION' will be flagged OPTION

With the actual test all my headers have OPTION instead of only one with OPTION (the one with the attribute product) and the others with TOTO. Thanks previous code has been edited!

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that your context for this template is something above topic (which makes sense because you test on topic/@product). That is why if you have 10 topic elements and one has @product='OPTION' then the WHEN is true.

If that is true and you want to test on current topic being output, then you would use `retrieve-marker` in the header and then create markers in the topic template and pull those markers into header.

Your choose would then become @product (because you are in the topic template) and you would just drop an `fo:marker` that would have your choose inside, then use `fo:retrieve-marker` and some `retrieve-position` depending on how you want them to be processed. If a topic always starts a page then you would use `first-including-carryover`.